# Using jQuery mouse click event to permanently change text in a DIV tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have setup javascript mouse click events to detect where on an image a user clicks, based on what area of the image is clicked text in a div tag is updated. The problem is the text in the div tag changes for a quick second, then reverts back to the original text in the HTML.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#area1").click(function (b) {
            $("#results").html("Text replaced by JS Mouse Click for area1");
        });  
        $("#area2").click(function (b) {
            $("#results").html("Text replaced by JS Mouse Click for area2");
        });             
        $("#area3").click(function (b) {
            $("#results").html("Text replaced by JS Mouse Click for area3");
        });   
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <img id="pic" usemap="#imagemap1" src="image.jpg" />
    <map id="imgmap" name="imagemap1">
        <area id="area1" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="51,46,25" href="" target="" />
        <area id="area2" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="71,131,25" href="" target="" />
        <area id="area3" shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="141,72,25" href="" target="" />
    </map>

    <div id="results">
        Original HTML Text
    </div>
```

The text in the DIV tag WILL change, but only for a second before returning to "Original HTML Text". How can I permanently change the text in the DIV tag until the user clicks on another part of the image map?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of jQuery? Also, what do you mean 'changes back', can you create a fiddle illustrating the issue?

Comment: Seems like it's refreshing the page, putting the original text back

Comment: just add `return false` at the end of your click handler to prevent the page using `href` of the anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a default action is triggering with your clicks, refreshing the page. Try preventing that. Also, I shortened your 3 click handlers into one.

```
$("[id^='area']").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#results").html("Text replaced by JS Mouse Click for " + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find more info about these "default actions"? Is that javascript, HTML or browser-based?

Comment: This should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a better solution.

1. Target all children of #area
2. Do you really want to hardcode your text in your JavaScript ? Use the data attribute and you'll be able to generate that server side. using $(e.currentTarget) you'll also be able to access your coordinates and other attributes that you have there.

Now you can reduce your code significantly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#imgmap area").click(function (e) {
            var description = $(e.currentTarget).data("description");
            e.preventDefault();
           $("#results").text(description);
        });  
    });
```

From what I understand, people like cats and JSFiddles. So here is a JSFiddle with a cat to demonstrate the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/27QtT/